# How to change a particular char in a string?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot that gives me gif when I say !gif in a particular channel. The problem I am facing is when I type # it cannot change itself to %23 as it is used in links. I just want a way to change # in the string to %23. Please help me for that. The whole code is given below. I am very new to python so if you want any other errors please fix it and also clean up the code.I am using the tenor API Thank you

Code :

```
import discord
import os
import json
import requests
import random

client = discord.Client()

global search_term_public 
global url
search_term_public = "Rick Roll"

def tenor():
    global url
    # set the apikey 
    apikey = (os.getenv("TENORAPIKEY"))

    # our test search
    search_term = search_term_public

    # get the GIFs for the search term
    r = requests.get("https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q=%s&key=%s&contentfilter=high" % (search_term, apikey))

    if r.status_code == 200:
            # load the GIFs using the urls for the smaller GIF sizes
            top_8gifs = json.loads(r.content)
            g = len(top_8gifs['results'])
            i = random.randint(0,g)
            if(i == g):
                    i = g-1
            h = str(g)
            f = str(i)
            url = top_8gifs['results'][i]['media'][0]['gif']['url']
            print("The number picked is " + f +" out of " + h + ". Search Term : " + search_term + ". Url : " +url)
    else:
            top_8gifs = None
    return url
@client.event
async def on_ready():
        print("Bot has successfully logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
        global search_term_public
        if message.author == client:
                return
        if message.content.startswith("!gif") and message.channel.id == 831789159587774504:
                # put the search term into the public variable. split the content with space and the second or more than second word should be in a variable
                tokens = message.content.split(' ')
                if tokens.__contains__(""):
                        tokens.remove("!gif")
                        tokens.remove("")
                elif tokens.__contains__("#"):
                        # I want to change # in the token and change it to %23
                        print()
                else :
                        tokens.remove("!gif")     
                search_term_public =  ("".join(tokens))
                if search_term_public == "":
                        search_term_public = "Rick Roll"
                        await message.channel.send("You got rick rolled!")
                url = tenor()
                await message.channel.send(url)

client.run(os.getenv("DISCORDTOKEN"))
```

Comment: To replace a character in a string, you use `s.replace('#','%23')`.  However, `tokens` is not a string, it is a list of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it might work

You can just use the "replace"  as follows

```
elif tokens.__contains__("#"):
        token=token.replace("#","%23")
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to look at
[url encoding](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlencode) probably.

However, to directly answer the question as a hotfix, I think you can do this directly after the `.split()` line

```
tokens = [token.replace('#', '%23') for token in tokens]
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code and what you mean as I don't understand as I am very new to python

Comment: What you are looking at is a [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/).
If we try to translate this code to English, it might sound like:

create a new list called `tokens`. Then, for every token in the existing list of tokens, apply the [replace](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) function on it, and save that to the new `tokens` list instead of what the original value was.

List comprehensions are great when you need to get a new list that is the result of making some small change to each member of an existing list.

Comment: Well I tested it and your answer is also correct but stack overflow doesn't allow me to accept both the answers but remember yours is correct too